# Access custom BIP32 paths on trezor

Tags: bip32-hd-wallets, trezor, dash

So I really have 2 problems now:

- I took xpub address for Dash from trezor and used it with blockcypher API to generate addresses with paths like m/0, m/1, etc
  I sent some money to that addresses and noticed that trezor wouldn't show them, obviously it uses different paths than blockcypher.
- I figured that easiest way is to take mnemonic and import it somewhere else, that would allow me to specify custom path, but I can't seem to find it. So I have trezor and I can access it, withdraw all the other funds from it, but I don't have mnemonic anymore.

What are my options to recover those Dash?

Comment: I don't feel confident enough to fork trezor firmware, modify paths and install it to my device. Are there other easier options?

Comment: If you have the Trezor and can access the device, why not just re-copy your mnemonic? Does trezor only display the phrase on initialization, and then never again?

Answer (score 2):

The Trezor doesn't actually only derive at specific derivation paths. Rather it has to be given a derivation path, and the Trezor web wallet software only uses predefined ones. However you can use another tool that connects to the Trezor and specify your own derivation paths.

Trezor has a command line tool as part of their python library that you can use. See https://github.com/trezor/python-trezor/blob/master/docs/OPTIONS.rst. You should be able to use that to construct a transaction that uses the addresses that you want.